# select query with contain condition in datatable using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datatable, django-queryset

I have a datatable and i need to put **CONTAINS** condition in it.Now am retrieving datatable rows using below query

```
DataRow[] resultss = dtDocument.Select("DocumentElementText='" + columnValue + "'");
```

but i need to put condition like contains in this query for retrieving values from datatable.

[image]

above is my datatable. this query  `dtDocument.Select("DocumentElementText='New Package'");` will return me the first row from the datatable.What i need is , i need to retrieve the row which contains  `<td>NAME</td>` from this datatable. How to retrieve the row ..??

Regards 
Arshad

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DataRow[] resultss = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("DocumentElementText").Contains("Enter Your String Here")).Select(row => row).ToArray<DataRow>();
```